# how to find closed cycles using neo4j

Tags: cypher

I need to find the meshes (closed cycles) of a circuit to apply Kirchhoff's laws (I just need the cycles that do not contain other cycles in). I already have the model created with nodes and connections.

I hope for your help on the closest query to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried

```
MATCH p=(n)-[*2..3]-(n) RETURN n, length(p), nodes(p), relationships(p)
```

This query is very slow so, I set 2 to 3 relationship limit.

Comment: It's a good start, how could you avoid repeating the results? because each cycle has several nodes and when obtaining the cycles that all the nodes can form, repeated results are generated

Comment: What you mean by repeating results? Cypher will traverse a relation just once, for preventing infinite loop.